# Chrome Extension - How does my extension maintain the session of the user

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome-extension

my popup has multiple divs on 1 HTML file that are displayed depending on the situation. Lets say my user creates a playlist for music and wants to annotate something, but leaves the popup for a minute, once the user clicks back on the extension icon, it goes back to the initial menu. What is the strategy behind keeping the session of the user even if they close the popup?

Comment: What you're looking for is the background page or script. They can persist the session for as long as the extension is running, rather than only when the user interacts. This should set you on the right path: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978473/background-html-vs-background-js-chrome-extension

Comment: I think chrome extensions can use cookies of their own like other javascript applications.

Comment: Are you asking about Firebase Auth users?  The SDK already persists the signed in user.  Is something about that not working the way you expect?  If so, can you share the code?

Comment: I might try cookies. And yes I use the Firebase Auth but what I mean by session is whatever the user was working on.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a background script which will hold your session state.
Communicate between popup (browser action html) and background script can be done use messages api, or share the same localstorage.

Comment: so make a session state variable and store it in localstorage? I have a check authentication function, maybe do a if statement on the localstorage variable and display depending on that variable? I was also thinking of using cookies